# OnCollisionExit not called when parenting object

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

Basically, I am trying to implement very simple event system for player to interact with different objects.
Right now, I have three states:
OnCollisionEnter, OnCollisionStay and OnCollisionExit and when my player is standing on top of the pressure plate It calls OnCollisionStay and everything is working properly. When the player gets off the pressure plate OnCollisionExit is called.

The problem comes when an Item is picked up and placed on the pressure plate.

I am using simple parenting approach - just parent item on my players hand on the desired position using this piece of code:

```
ObjectIwantToPickUp.pickupRigidbody.isKinematic = true; //makes the rigidbody not be acted upon by forces
ObjectIwantToPickUp.transform.SetParent(myHands.transform); // sets the position of the object to your hand position
ObjectIwantToPickUp.transform.localPosition = ObjectIwantToPickUp.pickPosition; //makes the object become a child of the parent so that it moves with the hands
ObjectIwantToPickUp.transform.localEulerAngles = ObjectIwantToPickUp.rotatePosition;
```

After that, if I pick up the item again, the item is parented, but the pressure plate stays active, since OnCollisionExit does not being called.
I tried replacing OnCollision methods with OnTrigger but the issue still persists.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

[`OnCollisionEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html), [`OnCollisionExit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionExit.html) and [`OnCollisionStay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionStay.html) will only call on components that share the same GameObject as the collider and a non-kinematic [`Rigidbody`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html).

Make sure the instance of your script is on the right GameObject.

---

You could try attaching an [`EventTrigger`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventTrigger.html) and dynamically add event hooks after your reparenting (not recommended).

Comment: Yes. Everything is set properly and it is working. On parenting object and get back it in to my hand onCollisionExit is not called, that is the problem. Otherwise it is all good

Comment: Are you calling it on the pressure plate or on the player? Make sure you're calling it from the right object (AKA. the player).

Comment: Hey. Maybe I am not explaining it well.For the Player is working, for the any game object that is with the proper tag is working too. If I move my game object with physics (aka if I collide with it) it is working too.

The only way when it is not working is if I parent the gameobject into my hand.
Then -> OnCollisionExit is not called. I am looking for that fix.